# what is the use of go-pear.php ? What it does actually?

Tags: php, pear

Can anybody tell me why do we need to install a set of classes using a script ?

PHP PEAR Lib is essentially a set of classes, is it fairly good to just copy in the hosting server.

So is go-pear.bat go-pear.php is necessary or its an optional. If it is necessary would like to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a tool to help install PEAR classes *for all users on the machine*.

If you are only going to use a PEAR class in a single project, you can easily just grab the class from it's download page and bundle it with the app.

Comment: is it not enought just to copy even for all users in a hosting site. Again its a bunch of classes. what is the need for install script. pls explain.

Comment: it changes the php.ini, adds elements to PATH, sets up the repository to keep track of installed modules and so on and on. But you might be interested in Pyrus, which seems a bit more straight-forward to me. More like the "why not simply copy that files and done"-approach you've implied. see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installationpyrus.introduction.php